# Why does devise not hash reset_password_token and confirmation_token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, devise

I figured out that the devise authentication framework for Rails does not hash the reset_password_token and the confirmation_token in the database? Does anyone know why?

Obviously it is a bad approach to store such a value in plain text in the database, as everyone who has access to the database can reuse the tokens and send them directly to the API (e.g. one can easily trigger a password reset, without having access to the email). Furthermore this is just a minimal effort to store the hash in the database. That's why I wonder what the ideas are behind this approach of plain tokens?

---

Update: Does no one has any opinion on that? From my point this is a security issue but it looks as I am the only one who is concerned about that :D

Comment: Do you have another solution?

Comment: Hash them e.g. with SHA512 and store the hash in the database. Send the client the plain text token by mail and if they click on the link, hash the provided token and use this as a query parameter to the database.

Answer (score 0):

There wouldn't be any point hashing them in the database. The confirmation/reset email would still have to send a token to the user that the app could use to identify them (an invitation/password reset token) against the hashed key you are storing. If this was stored in plaintext or a 2-way encryption then you would have exactly the same problem, as a hacker could just use the plaintext token and your app would happily hash it and authenticate them. If this was stored as 1-way encryption then your app wouldn't be able to extract the actual token it should send to the user.

Someone has to know the actual, unhashed version of a password/token. In passwords, the actual password is stored in the user's head. In this instance, then actual token needs to be stored in the database.

Comment: It is true that if the attacker gets access to the mail, he can reset the password as it stores the reset token always in plain (within the email content).
I speak from a point of view where a sysadmin or anyone else who has access to the database, could use such a token to reset the password of a user and then login with this password.

Comment: OK - but the system would somehow need to work out what token to include in the password reset link. Since the hash of the token would be a 1-way hash, the only way it could know this would be to store the token in plaintext as well, which would defeat the point of having the hash!